# .NET core interop with Xilinx SDK

Tags: .net-core, xilinx

I'm trying to get .NET core talking to a Xilinx SDK shared library.

I've no idea where to begin and there doesn't seem to be much on the internet about this.

Has anyone done this?

Comment: I'm using peta Linux.

Comment: You should use https://github.com/mono/CppSharp or http://www.swig.org/ to generate wrapper over the native library.